# Taylor series approximations: why do we take the sum from $n = 0$ to infinity if $p(x)$ is of order $n$?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I'm finding this topic very confusing and would appreciate some clarification (please keep in mind I'm a student, so I may not understand excessively formal explanations/mathematical notation).

My confusion is twofold:

**Is it an approximation or exact?**

We talk about Taylor series **approximations**, yet most definitions of a Taylor series I've seen use an equality:

$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{n}(a)(x-a)^n}{n!}$

Which one is it? Why do we use the equality sign above if we're approximating the function?

**Why do we take the sum to infinity instead of stopping at n?**

Let $p_{n, a}(x)$ be the nth-degree polynomial centered at $a$ that approximates $f(x)$. This function has the same value as $f$ at the point $a$: $f(a) = p_{n,a}(a)$. Furthermore, it has the same derivative as the function all the way up to the $n$-th derivative: $f^{n}(a) = p_{n,a}^{n}(a)$.

Why, then, do we take the sum from $n = 0$ to $n = \infty$ if the $n + 1$ and beyond derivatives are no longer equal?

Comment: Of course $\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{n}(a)(x-a)^n}{n!}$ is going to have wrong $k+1$ derivative and above. On the other hand $\sum_{n=0}^{k+1} \frac{f^{n}(a)(x-a)^n}{n!}$ has the correct $k+1$ derivative, although the $k+2$ derivative and above are still wrong. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{n}(a)(x-a)^n}{n!}$ has _all_ derivatives correct.

Comment: If we stop at some point we make an error (which can be estimated by the Lagrange remainder, for example). If we take the whole sum we have the exact value.

Comment: Oh, I think this is starting to make some sense thanks to @Arthur and Peter's comments. So the Lagrange remainder is only used when we are working with $p_{n,a}(x)$ as an approximation of $f(x)$, as opposed to the infinite sum? That is, in stopping short, we introduce an error to our approximation because it's no longer good for certain intervals of $x$ that aren't super close to $a$?

Comment: The (Lagrange, or other) remainder allows you to get an _upper bound_ on the error you make but you don't necessarily make an error: the $n$-th order 'approximation' of a polynomial function of order $n$, is _exact_, of course!

Comment: @StackTD If we have a polynomial, the taylor series is finite, this case does not apply here because it is about non-terminating series.

Comment: @AleksandrH True that the Lagrange remainder is only the worst case, but if we stop at some point , we will almost always get bad approximations if we are too for away from $a$, we could by chance get a good value, but this is the exception.

Comment: Not sure why you would (need to) make the distinction, you may not know _a priori_ if the series is finite or not (of course I know it is, for a polynomial)...? I wasn't trying to confuse OP, apologies if I did.